# JQUERY, Dynamically text box id assign to focusout function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var CurrentTextBoxID = "";
var shifton = false;
var IsCapsLockOn = false;   

// toggles the keyboard to show or hide when link is clicked
$(":text").focus(function(e) {              
    CurrentTextBoxID = this.id;
    var top = ($(window).height() - $('#keyboard').height()) - 25;        
    var left = ($(window).width() - $('#keyboard').width()) / 2;

    alert(CurrentTextBoxID + " focus In");

    $('#keyboard').css(
        {               
            "left": left+"px",
            "top": top+"px"
        }
    ).toggle();

});

$('#'+CurrentTextBoxID).blur(function() {
    alert("**");
});


$('#'+CurrentTextBoxID).focusout(function() {
    alert(this.id + " focus out");
});
```

At this upper code, blur function and focusout function did not work.
When I change code like that it work.

```
$('#txtTest1').blur(function() {
    alert("**");
});


$('#txtTest1').focusout(function() {
    alert(this.id + " focus out");
});
```

But by changing code like that, I cannot give text box ID dynamically.
So, Please let me know how could i make like that.

```
$( DYNAMIC ID ).focusout(function() { .... });
```

Comment: are you getting correct id in `alert(CurrentTextBoxID + " focus In");` ?

Comment: Yes sure i get correct id in alert(CurrentTextBoxID + " focus In");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I feel you need to bind those `blur` and `focusout` function for all text boxes. If you do it one by one in `focus` (as in the answer of  @Gabe)function you will be binding that function again when some next `focus` event happens.
I think you need to do like this,

```
$(":text").blur(function() {
    alert("**");
    var element=$(this); // you can get the element here
});


$(":text").focusout(function() {
    alert(this.id + " focus out");
});
```

Comment: Yea thanks for echoing what I said. I mentioned NOT to do it this way and explained why it's not currently working. Then offered better solutions.

Comment: Ah, My answer is written after your first answer. I didn't see the edit. :(

Answer (score 3):

Move the `blur()` and `focusout()` inside `focus()` where `CurrentTextBoxID` is defined.
This seems kind of hacky to me.

The best thing to do would be to bind the event to the `textbox` when its added dynamically. I would use `live()` way of binding your events in this case. The below would work but it binds and event everytime the `textbox` gets `focus`.

`CurrentTextBoxID` is `undefined` the way you are doing it, you could do this but better examples follow.

```
$(":text").focus(function(e) {              
    CurrentTextBoxID = this.id;
    var top = ($(window).height() - $('#keyboard').height()) - 25;        
    var left = ($(window).width() - $('#keyboard').width()) / 2;

    alert(CurrentTextBoxID + " focus In");

    $('#keyboard').css(
        {               
            "left": left+"px",
            "top": top+"px"
        }
    ).toggle();

    $('#'+CurrentTextBoxID).blur(function() {
       alert("**");
    });


    $('#'+CurrentTextBoxID).focusout(function() {
       alert(this.id + " focus out");
    });


});
```

Alternatively you could use `live()` to bind the textboxes

```
$('.dynamicTextBox').live('blur', function(){
   alert("**");
});
```

Or even...

```
$(':text').blur(function(){
   alert("**" + $(this).attr('id'));
});

$(':text').focusout(function(){
   alert("**" + $(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: So my answered solved your problem and you mark a different answer as the solution to the question?

Comment: As Gabe and Jayantha give suggestion, I change my code like that. It work.
Thank both of you.

    $(document).ready(function(){
    var CurrentTextBoxID = "";
 ....
  $(":text").focus(function(e) {
  ...});
  
  $(":text").focusout(function() {
   alert(this.id + " focus out");
  });